# Elasticsearch for repeated data on different websites

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the main database with videos and several websites. Each website has 40-60% of random videos from the main database. I want to use only one elasticsearch instance with video index from the main database, but search only from videos on given websites (40-60%). How can I implement this feature? Or should I create a separate index for each website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways in my opinion. Elasticsearch is very flexible here.

1. Index the videos in separate indices. It will be easy when searching but you need to route the videos into the right index and have duplicate data.
2. Index the videos in one index and define a discriminator propery like targetWebsite. When searching, filter on this property.
3. Combine 1+2: Use a [index alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) for each website, where you define the [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered) too. Easy searching, easy indexing, no duplicate data.
4. Index website specific videos into website indices. Common videos, available on each website into separate index. For each website define a alias and assign the website specific index and the common index too. Then you'll search in both indices at single time.

BTW: Always use aliases. They are very handy, especially when you need to maintain your indices with no downtime.